# Nested form not showing fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `nested form` based in a `has_one` relationship but it's not showing the fields.

What am I missing?

New action

```
  def new
    @doctor = Doctor.new    
    1.times { @doctor.build_schedule }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @doctor }
    end
  end
```

_form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@doctor, :html => { class: "form-horizontal"})  do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :name %>

        <%= f.simple_fields_for :schedule do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'days_checkboxes', :f => builder %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Model

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :schedule, dependent: :destroy

end
```

Do I have to set the build in other actions?

Comment: Which "other actions" do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no `schedule` associated object on your model instance, yes you will need to call `build_schedule` wherever you want to reference it. If you didn't do this, the form wouldn't render at all because it has nothing to display the fields for.

Comment: I'm using Active Admin, if I try to edit the record through Active Admin (localhost... /admin/doctor/new/...), I can't see the nested form, but if I access directly (localhost.../doctor/new...) then I can see the nested form. what should I do?

Comment: my guess is that you don't have a before filter (or whatever it is that AA uses) that calls `build_schedule.`